# Is there a way I can display data via a line graph/pie chart in an wp7 application?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, graph

So I want to add an extra feature to this application. I want the user to be able to see a graphical representation of their monthly outgoing expenditure and monthly income.
 Similarly to this ([droid wallet](https://lh5.ggpht.com/2vl2JZzsra60Nlm2ldr4IYElwlvg4BrEpvDxG4sc4yuuDVUE1otooYDtJj3hSwfoOY4)) but albeit on a Windows Phone device instead and this [myMoneyBook](http://image.catalog.zune.net/v3.2/image/184f6a09-ff92-4dcf-b9e3-e987fdc7aad5?width=160&height=160)

Does anyone know about I can go about doing this, or point me in the right place on what to look/read up on?

Comment: http://www.visiblox.com/

Comment: you also might want to check out some 3rd party data visualization products such as Infragistics

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/2502/Windows_Phone_7_RTM_charting_using_the_Silverlight_Control_Toolkit.aspx) page describes how to get a pie chart on Windows Phone 7 using the Silverlight 3 toolkit. Since Mango supports Silverlight 4 you may be able to get it to work using the Silverlight 4 toolkit as well.

Comment: What about the latest Silverlight 5 toolkit? http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435

Comment: @AlexDuncan You might run into the same problem that the guy who wrote that article did; Silverlight 5 is not supported on the phone, so if the control uses any features from it your application will crash.

Comment: I hear you, makes sense I guess, do you know of any tutorial guides available demonstrating how to use it to display data?

Comment: @AlexDuncan I found [this page](http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl2/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html?path=DataVisualization) when I searched for **Silverlight DataVisualization Toolkit**. You'll be able to find documentation for the Silverlight toolkit from similar searches, the only problem is that since they're at version 5 and you're limited to using 3 or 4 you'll have to make sure you're looking at the right version of the docs.